# Can a bottom sign be omitted in a disjunction?

Tags: solution-verification, first-order-logic

I have got the following statement:
∀aP(a),∀a(¬P(a)∨S(a)) ⊢∀a S(a)∨¬P(a)

My proof looks like this:

1. ∀aP(a) (premise)
2. ∀a(¬P(a)∨S(a)) (premise)

Start scope of x as substitution of a

3. P(x) (forall elimination 1)
4. ¬P(x) ∨ S(x) (forall elimination 2)
5. P(x) (¬P(x) ∧ S(x)) (∧-introduction 3, 4)
6. (P(a)∧¬P(a))∨(P(a)∧S(a)) (distributive law 5)
7. (⊥)∨(P(a)∧S(a)) (¬-elimination 6)
8. P(a)∧S(a) (⊥-elimination 7)
9. S(x) (∧-elimination 8)

End Scope of x

10. ∀a S(a) (∀a-introduction 9)
11. ∀aS(a)∨¬P(a) (∨-introduction 10)

Is it possible to simply eliminate the bottom in the disjunction with given a more formal disjunction elimination?

Answer (score 0):

Rules of Inference apply only to whole statements, not parts of statements, so neither the $\neg$-elimination (line 7) nor the $\bot$-elimination (line 8) attempts are valid inferences.

Rather, I suggest applying $\vee$-elimination, to assess the disjuncts of line $6$ individually.  (Though to save work, I would do so on line $4$ instead.)

---

Additionally, that is not what $\bot$-elimination means. The rule, also known as *ex falso quodlibet*, or the Rule of Explosion, is the rule that $\bot$ allows the inference of any statement ; anything may be inferred from a contradiction.

---

Finally, the $\vee$ introduction should take place before the $\forall$-introduction.  $\forall a~S(a)\vee\neg P(a)$ should be read as $\forall a~(S(a)\vee\neg P(a))$ .